# make: *** [all] Error 2

Tags: terminal, macintosh

I tried to install a decompiler on my macbook, but the terminal returned errors below.

```
ouekihodos-MacBook-Pro:radare2 LewisWang$ gmake
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C libr/util
../config.mk:29: /Users/LewisWang/Desktop/Computer: No such file or directory
../config.mk:29: Programming/Hack/radare2/libr/../global.mk: No such file or directory
../config.mk:30: /Users/LewisWang/Desktop/Computer: No such file or directory
../config.mk:30: Programming/Hack/radare2/libr/../mk/.mk: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `Programming/Hack/radare2/libr/../mk/.mk'.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The output looks like word splitting has occurred. Try installing it in a path that contains no spaces/special chars.

Comment: @user000001 you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @derobert It was more of a guess than a definite answer, but I added one since you asked for it.

Comment: I've tried and it works well!

Comment: but how to post this as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the error message the output looks suspicious: You have `/Users/LewisWang/Desktop/Computer` and the next error `Programming/Hack/radare2/libr/../global.mk`. It looks like the actual path is

```
/Users/LewisWang/Desktop/Computer Programming/Hack/radare2/libr/../global.mk
```

And that the make scripts fails to parse it correctly. A common reason for word splitting to happen is if somebody forgot to quote a shell variable, like writing

```
touch $file
```

... instead of

```
touch "$file"
```

If you try to install it in a path that contains no spaces, I suspect that the error messages (if any) will be different.